# Selecting everything upwards from where the cursor is

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to select everything upwards from where the cursor is. Kind of like `Ctrl + Shift + Up` does, but not just a line, everything.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: add a keybinding to command `cursorTopSelect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selectiing updaward from from where the cursor is , you can use ctrl + shift + home

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a "deticated" home button (so I want to change the key binding). Do you perhaps now the name of the option (upward selecting)?