# How to delete all lines above the current one in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a massive file full of SQL statements and I would like to delete half of them to reduce the amount of insert statements to make the data more manageable. How can I delete all lines above the line which my cursor is in (or using a range of line numbers)?

Comment: Same https://stackoverflow.com/a/60948217/836330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic text editing shortcuts:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>HOME</kbd> to select all from current cursor to start of document.

<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete.